# How to change directories on console application

Tags: c#, directory, console-application

I am creating a simple explorer program for an assignment on c# and have the directory set to `c:\\Windows`

How you would be able to change the directory from the default windows to something else in the console.

Answer (score 18):

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"c:\program files\");
```

Comment: say if i had multiple methods how would i make it so that if i type 4 on an options screen and change to a different directory how would i get it to keep the new directory when it goes back to start screen ?

Comment: Please be cautious! This API call changes the current working directory of your application. So, if you load any assemblies at run time which were present at the original location (from where your executable had started) will fail to load.

Answer (score 7):

You can set [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) property for your directory path.

> Gets or sets the fully qualified path of the current working
>   directory.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\Windows";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try setting `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to the value you want.

In your case:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\Windows";
```